# Swipe gesture being added to a UIView or UIViewController upon segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiview

I'm completely stumped by this. I've been working on a project that has both a landscape view and portrait view. I segue from one view controller to another, and the 2nd view controller has a UIView that allows custom drawing. However, when I'm in landscape mode (and only when in landscape mode), I'm unable to draw in the view (with touches... functions) because when I'm in the left half of the view and I drag towards the left side of the screen, I get taken back to the previous view controller.

The view controllers are embedded in a navigation controller, so I'm not sure if this is some built-in segue that the navigation controller creates to send me back or something, but other than that there's nothing I can think of that'd be causing this.

Any idea what may be causing this? I've already checked the UIView itself and there are no gesture recognizers associated with it, so I don't know where it'd be hiding.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

Add this to you viewDidLoad function of your second view controller.

iOS 7 and above has a feature to go back to previous view controller when swipe from the left end

**UPDATE**

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self

func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer!) -> Bool {
return false;
}
```

Comment: Well it stopped working just now for some reason. I didn't change the code besides converting it to swift, and it worked for about 10 minutes, but now stopped working.

Comment: try this
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self

func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer!) -> Bool {
    return false;
}

Comment: see the update above. set the delegate for interactivePopGestureRecognizer in viewDidLoad and add the function to the view controller

Comment: It's giving me a naming error because I have the function func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool), and it's saying there's a naming issue with self.navigationController. It didn't (doesn't) say that with the previous code submitted.